# Is there a way to create a dataframe given list objects where the column names in the dataframe are the variable names of each list?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe with list objects in a way that the column names of the dataframe will be the variable names of the list objects and the values of the list will be binded to each column. Example: Given the lists

```
badStateInputs <- list("nd", "NORTH DAKOTA", "N. Dakota", "N DAKOTA", "VT", "V   t", "Nevada")
emptyOrNonString <- list(NULL, "", "   ", 3, numeric(), character(), 1.34)
```

What's the best way to get a dataframe that looks like

```
 "badStateInputs"  "emptyOrNonString"
1      "nd"                NULL
2    "NORTH"               ""
3       etc.               etc.
```

I tried:

```
test.data <- data.frame(badStateInputs, emptyOrNonString, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and it threw

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Sorry I'm new to R so having to learn about the different kinds of objects is providing a learning curve. I want to be able to loop through each row for testing purposes like:

```
    for(input in 1:nrow(test.data[input, "badStateInputs"]))
    {
       expected <- input
       actual <- foo(...)
       expect_equal(actual, input)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the real requirements here are, but one thing to keep in mind is that while lists can hold objects of any mix of types (character, numeric, other lists) data frame columns _must_ be a single type. So it might possibly be worth rethinking building a data frame out of _lists_ that are supposed to be columns...?

Comment: okay thank you. I'll just create a list of lists and attempt to loop through columns that way.

Comment: As an add-on to that, while a list element can be `NULL`, but atomic vectors like `character` or `factor` vectors cannot have a `NULL` element. So when you show a data frame with a `NULL` in it, then the class of that column must be a `list`.

Comment: To further Gregor's addendum to joran's comment: while this *"works"*, `x <- data.frame(a=1:7, b=1:7); x$a <- badStateInputs; x$b <- emptyOrNonString`, it is IMO not a good way to package the data: many things that expect "normal" frames will not deal well with this type of structure.